# Java Generics: Cannot create an array of a nested class

Tags: java, arrays, generics, inner-classes

I'm trying to convert an AVLTree implementation into a heap style array and am having some problems with generics:

```
public class MyAVLTree<K extends Comparable<? super K>, E> implements
    OrderedDictionary<K, E> {

    class AVLNode implements Locator<K, E>{
        // ...
    }

    // ....

    public Locator<K,E> [] toBSTArray() {
        AVLNode[] bArray = new AVLNode[size];
        makeArray(root, 0, bArray);  // recursion
        return bArray;
    }
}
```

At the line `AVLNode[] bArray = new AVLNode[size];` I get the following error:

> "Cannot create a generic array of MyAVLTree.AVLNode"

I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Any help?

Comment: does this fix it: `class AVLNode<K, E> implements Locator<K, E>` ?

Comment: @vikingsteve this should be an answer

Comment: @vikingsteve You are just hiding the type variable. I highly doubt that is wanted.

Comment: Thanks vikingsteve, that was my first thought, but as Radiodef stated, it didn't really fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inner classes capture the type variables from an outer class so this is why you get the error.

If you wish to instantiate a raw `AVLNode[]` you may qualify the class name as raw `MyAVLTree`:

```
//                     vvvvvvvvv
AVLNode[] bArray = new MyAVLTree.AVLNode[size];
```

You will get warnings as you normally would creating a raw array type; however this will compile. Be advised the usual things [that come along with raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) if you don't know them, although of course you cannot instantiate an array in Java that is not raw.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like it fixed the problem. I could swear I tried that and it didn't :)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds funny, but you *can* do such trick:

```
AVLNode[] bArray = (AVLNode[]) Array.newInstance(AVLNode.class, size);
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be another solution.

Comment: There is no point in using `Array.newInstance()` with a class hardcoded at compile time.