# Why static nested class?

Tags: java

I have a sample code for tries.The code seems have no compile errors. Why does it use static nested class node? when I delete `static` in `Node` nested class and compile, the error shows `create generic array` in `private Node[] next = new Node[R];`. What on earth happened?

```
public class TrieST<Value> {
    private static final int R = 256;        // extended ASCII


    private Node root;      // root of trie
    private int N;          // number of keys in trie

    // R-way trie node
    private static class Node {
        private Object val;
        private Node[] next = new Node[R];
    }


    public TrieST() {
    }
}
```

Comment: First, do you know why generic arrays aren't allowed? (e.g. `new ArrayList<String>[5];` shows this error)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a generic array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581002/how-to-create-a-generic-array)

Comment: Can you explain why there is no such error when static is added?

Comment: Because with static you create: `Node[] next = new Node[R]` and with non-static inner-class you create a Node that is associated with an instance of the outer-class, which has a generic type. And creation of generic arrays is forbidden.

Comment: Note that 'static inner' is a contradiction in terms. A nested class is *either* static *or* inner.

Comment: @EJP good catch, non-static was supposed to be in brackets.

Comment: See also ["Java Generics: Cannot create an array of a nested class"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26926920/2891664).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that in your code snippet you are using a non-static inner class instead of a static nested class like this: `private class Node`, in that case, you will be trying to instantiate an `Array` which is not possible, **we can't instantiate an `Array` in a generic class**, because  generics doesn't have any information regarding their type **at runtime**, while arrays creation expression **specifies** the element type.

So, the reason why using a [Static Nested Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) compiled, is that such classes are considered as a "top-level" class (in terms of behavior):

> A static nested class interacts with the instance members of its outer
>   class (and other classes) just like any other top-level class. In
>   effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class that
>   has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience.

Now, let's take all of this into consideration, and come back to the exact error displayed by the compiler:

> Cannot create a generic array of `TrieST<Value>.Node`

That means that the type of the `array` you want to create is `TrieST<Value>.Node` whose runtime's type is not known, thus different types may be inserted into the `next` array. More clear and well explained examples could be found in [Cannot Create Arrays of Parameterized Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays)

Whereas, a static Nested class is **not behaving** as an inner class of `TrieST<Value>` , thus instiating an array inside `Node` will not be illegal as it's not of the type `TrieST<Value>.Node`, its of the type `Node` (**like** if it's a top-level class) .

Comment: Can you explain more why and how nested static lass "suppress" this error consider as top level class?

Comment: a top-level class is a non inner class, so that means that there is no implicit relationship between the static nested class and the outer class, so instantiating an array dosn't affect the outer class (your generic class)

Comment: @Peterxwl I just added an update, please take a look now

Comment: 1. "a static Nested class is not considered as an inner class" - false. It *is* an inner static class. 2. "...its of the type Node (**your Top level class**)" - wrong again, a static class *behaves* like a top-level class but it's **not** one.

Comment: @alfas in the java docs "static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class " thats why i said "considered as", It's clear that it's not one! that's why i quoted the javadocs! but i used that termenology of 'considered' or 'so called' to clarify the issue

Comment: @alfasin *"It is an inner static class."* A static nested class isn't inner. [*"An inner class is a nested class that is not declared static."*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) A nested class can be either inner or static.

Answer (score 1):

Because with static you create: `Node[] next = new Node[R]` and with non-static inner-class you create a Node that is associated with an instance of the outer-class, which has a generic type. And creation of generic arrays is forbidden.

But lets back up a few steps: the way to instantiate an inner-class (non-static) is as follows (example):

```
class TrieST<V> {
    private static final int R = 256;        

    private Node root;      // root of trie
    private int N;          // number of keys in trie
    private TrieST<String> inst = new TrieST<String>(); // must create an instance of the outer class first

    // R-way trie node
    private class Node {
        private Object val;
        private TrieST<String>.Node next =  inst.new Node(); //must use an instance of the outer class to instantiate an object of the inner class
    }

    public TrieST() {
    }
}
```

Now, if we'll try to change the implementation above from an instance of the inner class to an array, we'll get [generic array creation](https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA120&ots=yZEiPfn-U3&dq=effective%20java%20%22generic%20array%20creation%22&pg=PA120#v=onepage&q=effective%20java%20%22generic%20array%20creation%22&f=false) because it's prohibited to create arrays with generic type due to the *covariance* nature of arrays (`Shape[]` is `super` of `Triangle[]`) which doesn't work well with the *invariant* nature of generics (`List<Object>` is *not* super of `List<String>`). In "Effective Java" Bloch provides a more detailed explanation if you want to dig in.

If you insist on using an inner-class, you can work around this restriction by using `Array.newInstance()` which can create array of a type known only at runtime as follows:

```
private Node[] next = (Node[]) Array.newInstance(Node.class, R);
```

Comment: what if I still want a 'Node[] next' in the non-static inner class?

Comment: @Peterxwl you can trick the compiler by doing: `private Node[] next = (Node[]) Array.newInstance(Node.class, R);` I'll add it to the answer.